# How to get partition information from non-booting server?

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, diskmanagement, partition, system-state

Need to manually rebuild a mirrored array on a server and am in the process of reinstalling SBS 2003 on it.  However, it's a Dell server, and know that there's the Dell FAT32 diagnostics partition, a system partition, and a data partition, but do not know the size of each.

Planning on reinstalling SBS 2003, all applications on the server, and then doing a System State restore, but figured that not having the correct partitions will cause some grief: am I right?  Almost thinking that the size of the partitions shouldn't matter, but not positive.

Question: should I care about the size of the partition?  If so, how can I get this partition information from a non-booting drive?  We have an Acronis image of the one working disk and the partitions are mounted/viewable in Explorer on a workstation, but I'm not sure where the Logical Disk Manager/Disk Management data is stored and/or if there's a way to retrieve it without having a working Windows installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe ask the partition table in your Acronis image. I do that on Linux for virtual machines disks. Maybe it works for you too.
Check on http://connaissances.fournier38.fr/display.php?id=328 (in French sorry) but the commands are easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php) live cd.

Comment: This won't work -- the array has been wiped/rebuilt with new disks -- all I have is the Acronis image (which I can mount/view the partitions and their data).  What I don't know is if I can find a cached .dat file (or registry key perhaps) that would have the size of the partitions, like perhaps something that the Disk Management utility would store.